# Flask keeps calling method from another blueprint

Tags: flask, http-status-code-404

I have a blueprint named 'main' with method for rendering template that shows Post by its slug.

```
main = Blueprint("main", __name__)
@main.route("/<slug>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def post(slug):
 post = Post.query.filter_by(slug=slug).first()

 print("TEST - main.post -> " + request.referrer)

 comments = (
    Comment.query.order_by(Comment.date_posted.desc())
    .filter_by(post_id=post.id)
    .all()
 )
 headImg = url_for(
    "static", filename="upload/media/images/head_Images/" + post.headImg
 )
 form = CommentForm()
 if form.validate_on_submit():
    comment = Comment(
        content=form.comment.data, user_id=current_user.id, post_id=post.id
    )
    db.session.add(comment)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Comment added", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("main.post", slug=post.slug))

 return render_template(
    "post.html",
    title=post.title,
    post=post,
    comments=comments,
    form=form,
    headImg=headImg,
 )
```

I also have other blueprints like 'users', 'posts', 'comments', 'logs', 'errors'...

```
from flaskblog.users.routes import users
from flaskblog.posts.routes import posts
from flaskblog.comments.routes import comments
from flaskblog.logs.routes import logs
from flaskblog.errors.routes import errors
from flaskblog.main.routes import main

app.register_blueprint(users)
app.register_blueprint(posts)
app.register_blueprint(comments)
app.register_blueprint(logs)
app.register_blueprint(errors)
app.register_blueprint(main)
```

App has one UI for public and one for admin users, and they use different base templates.
Whenever I click some link in my "admin" side (dashboard) 'main.post' gets called and 404 gets thrown as it cannot find and post without a slug.

Methods in dashboard are in different blueprints.

For example... I click `<a href="{{ url_for('logs.error_logs') }}></a>`, it opens correct template with correct url *"http://localhost:5000/admin/logs/error"*, but console shows an error:

```
TEST - ERROR LOGS
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2023 00:36:38] "GET /admin/logs/error HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2023 00:36:38] "GET /static/adminKit/app.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2023 00:36:38] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2023 00:36:38] "GET /static/adminKit/app.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
TEST - main.post -> http://localhost:5000/admin/logs/error
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2023 00:36:39] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\SoFtYTech\flaskblog\main\routes.py", line 218, in post
    .filter_by(post_id=post.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

In this case this is the 'errors' template that renders templates with tables filled with data from the database where I'm saving all requests and all errors.

```
logs = Blueprint("logs", __name__)


@logs.route("/admin/logs/request", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
@roles_required("Superadmin")
def request_logs():
    title = "Request Logs"

    requestLogs = RequestLog.query.all()

    return render_template(
        "admin/admin-request-logs.html",
        title=title,
        pageTitle=title,
        requestLogs=requestLogs,
    )


@logs.route("/admin/logs/error", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
@roles_required("Superadmin")
def error_logs():
    title = "Error Logs"
    errorLogs = ErrorLog.query.all()
    print("TEST - ERROR LOGS")

    return render_template(
        "admin/admin-test.html",
        title=title,
        pageTitle=title,
        errorLogs=errorLogs,
    )
```

Another example...clicking `<a class="sidebar-link" href="{{ url_for('posts.allPosts') }}"></a>` opens/renders correct template and still output is the same:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2023 00:54:10] "GET /admin/posts/all HTTP/1.1" 200 -
TEST - main.post -> http://localhost:5000/admin/posts/all
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2023 00:54:10] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\Virtual ENVs\softyVenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\ikoji\Python Projects\SoFtYTech\flaskblog\main\routes.py", line 218, in post
    .filter_by(post_id=post.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

And this is the 'posts' blueprint:

```
posts = Blueprint("posts", __name__)


# Dashoard - Table wih all posts with edit/delete buttons - New Design
@posts.route("/admin/posts/all")
@login_required
@roles_required(["Admin", "Superadmin"])
def allPosts():
    posts = Post.query.all()
    title = "All Posts"

    return render_template(
        "admin/admin-posts.html", posts=posts, pageTitle=title, title=title
    )
```

Public pages don't call 'main.post', so I thought that there is an issue with admin-base.html template and its incuded templates, as thats whats different. I removed each of them one by one and the issue stayed the same.

Nor Chat GPT, nor Google Bard can't see/find whats causing this issue. I can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with admin-base.html base template for all dashboard templates where issue was happening.

I was missing a favicon.

After adding

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
```

everything worked.